# ORACLE ASM unable to load module

Tags: oracle

```
uname -r is 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64

uname -a is Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 16 11:16:45 PDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

kmod-oracleasm-2.0.8-13.0.1.el6_8.x86_64
oracleasm-support-2.1.8-1.el6.x86_64
oracleasmlib-2.0.4-1.el6.x86_64

kernel-headers-2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64
kernel-devel-2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64
```

**

> [root@localhost Desktop]# /etc/init.d/oracleasm start Initializing the
>   Oracle ASMLib driver: [FAILED] [root@localhost Desktop]#
>   /etc/init.d/oracleasm configure -i Configuring the Oracle ASM library
>   driver. This will configure the on-boot properties of the Oracle ASM
>   library driver. The following questions will determine whether the
>   driver is loaded on boot and what permissions it will have. The
>   current values will be shown in brackets ('[]'). Hitting without
>   typing an answer will keep that current value. Ctrl-C will abort.
>   Default user to own the driver interface [oracle]: Default group to
>   own the driver interface [dba]: Start Oracle ASM library driver on
>   boot (y/n) [y]: Scan for Oracle ASM disks on boot (y/n) [y]: Writing
>   Oracle ASM library driver configuration: done Initializing the Oracle
>   ASMLib driver: [FAILED]

**

Please provide me the solution.

Comment: Were any log files produced? Either Oracle-specific ones, or something relevant in the server logs? Not much to go on here...

Comment: Creating /dev/oracleasm mount point: /dev/oracleasm
Loading module "oracleasm": failed
Unable to load module "oracleasm"
Loading module "oracleasm": failed
Unable to load module "oracleasm"

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/oracleasm` log file?

Comment: Same data is followed.                           Creating /dev/oracleasm mount point: /dev/oracleasm
Loading module "oracleasm": failed
Unable to load module "oracleasm"
Creating /dev/oracleasm mount point: /dev/oracleasm
Loading module "oracleasm": failed
Unable to load module "oracleasm"
Loading module "oracleasm": failed
Unable to load module "oracleasm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself solved it. The problem was with kernel.
In ole6.5 we don't need to install oracleasm it is already present. Only oracle-support and oraclelib are to be installed.